# How do I use HTML compression in Jimdo WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: html, page-speed, compression, wysiwyg

I have used Jimdo website to build my website. Using Google PageSpeed Insights tell me that I can achieve better page load speed using HTML compression. I wanted to use *deflate.js* and *inflate.js*, but the access to Jimdo *.htaccess* file is  not there, as Jimdo generates the HTML on the fly.

Has anyone faced this problem before? and if they have solved it or achieved HTML compression in Jimdo, how they have done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I use for HTML compression using PHP is documented quite well by David Walsh on his website: http://davidwalsh.name/php-output-buffers.

If you're not using PHP I would think an equivalent solution would be available in your server-side language of choice. This isn't however something you can accomplish with just client-side code or by preparing/saving your HTML file in a different way.

Comment: Looking more carefully at Jimdo, it seems rather than being a content management system its actually a hosted service - therefore unless they implement or have already implemented this feature on their service you will be unable to use it. Having checked their website with an HTTP request including the header "Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate" the response returned was not compressed, therefore I believe they have not at this time implemented page compression.

Comment: @richallstoke Yes i contacted them and they are saying that it is not available. I was in hope of a hack/ Technique which may get me the same solution...

Comment: If you have control of your domain name and DNS then one other option available to you could be to use a website acceleration service such as CloudFlare, whose infrastructure would sit like a proxy service inbetween your current hosting provider (Jimdo) and your end-users and apply all kinds of speed optimization and compression techniques when delivering your website to them. They offer a free service or different tiers of paid services depending on the level of features you're after. Other similar providers exist also. (I've not as yet tried CloudFlare myself).

Comment: @richallstoke. Thanks.. Your suggestion was quite usable.